# Allow Scrolling in DIV when hovering a fixed element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container `div` with a `button` and a car `img` inside of it. The car moves when the page is scrolled.

When the mouse is hovering over top of the `button` or `img`, the scroll wheel no longer works.

I tried adding a gray overlay `div` to block the `hover` on the button and car. But this prevents the button from being clicked.

Is there a way to make scrolling work even when the button or image is hovered?

```js
$('#home').on('scroll', function() {

 var dist = $(this).scrollTop();

 $('#cars').css('left', dist / 2);
  
});
```

```css
body {
  position : absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  background: #fff;
}
#overlay {
 height: 1200px;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 z-index: 999;
 position: relative;
 pointer-events: none;
}
#buttons {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#home {
 
    position: relative;
    top:0px;
    width: calc(100% + 25px);
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-image: url('images/movie_6.jpg');
   height: 400px;
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 40px;


}
#homeinner {
 height: 1800px;
 overflow: hidden;
}
#cars {
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
}

#bar {
  height: 80px;
  width: calc(100% + 25px);
  position: absolute;
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
  <div id="homeinner">
   
    <button id="buttons" onclick="alert('Log in page!')">
button
    </button>
    <img id="cars"   src="http://www.kindaholidays.com/hotel/img/travel_icon/512x512/car.png" />
  
  <div id="overlay">
   
   </div>
   </div>

</section>

<div id="bar">
</div>
```

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/3gn6abq8/24/

Comment: @Tom it doesn't click on "button" :\

Comment: You need to clarify your question then because I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: @Tom Well, I want the gray overlaying div `to allow only click, but not any other events like hovering and so on`, hope it's a bit more clear.

Comment: So don't bind any events other than click to it. Or do you mean you want its existence to block some events, or on hover of the element, other events shouldn't trigger? A degree of clarity is required.

Comment: @Popnoodles It's meant to block "hovering" on the `button` or the `car image`, because this way it's not moving the car to the right. 
Here, http://jsfiddle.net/denea/3gn6abq8/28/, this way it's doing the job, but I can't click on the button, while if I change `pointer-events: none` it's not doing the job.

Comment: I don't understand why it wouldn't either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I realize now that your issue is that when the mouse is over top of the button or car image, mousewheel scrolling does not work. This is because the position of those elements is "fixed". I'm not sure if this is a bug or not. Anyways, you can simulate the fixed position with javascript to get around this issue.

```js
$('#home').on('scroll', function() {
  var dist = $(this).scrollTop();

  $("#buttons").css("top", dist);
  $("#cars").css("top", dist + 100);

  $('#cars').css('left', dist / 2);

});
```

```css
body {
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  background: #fff;
}
#overlay {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  z-index: 999;
  position: relative;
  pointer-events: none;
}
#buttons {
  width: 150px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 5;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#home {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  width: calc(100% + 25px);
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-image: url('images/movie_6.jpg');
  height: 400px;
  background-color: #000000;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
#homeinner {
  height: 1800px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#cars {
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
}
#bar {
  height: 80px;
  width: calc(100% + 25px);
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="home">
  <div id="homeinner">

    <button id="buttons" onclick="alert('Log in page!')">
      button
    </button>
    <img id="cars" src="http://www.kindaholidays.com/hotel/img/travel_icon/512x512/car.png" />

  </div>

</section>

<div id="bar">
</div>
```

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks for all your help, next time I'll think twice when I ask something and think how to explain it better.